# MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream (after a period of inactivity)

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, compose-db

I get this error on a `find` call (default Java Driver) after a period of inactivity. I tried to add a manual heartbeat (writing to a capped collection), but it didn't help. I only get the issue while being connected to an instance on compose (i.e. not in a local context).

MongoDB version is 3.2.8, latest driver (3.3), using Java 8.

Any idea ?

Comment: I found out that the `isSocketKeepAlive` flag of the `MongoClientOptions` is `false` by default, I changed it to true and I'm now waiting to see if I get the error again.

Comment: unfortunatly, with .socketKeepAlive(true), we also get this error, my drive version is 3.0.4

Comment: could you find the reason at last? I face to this error now

Comment: Can you check how many connections you have available?  Run this from the mongo shell: `db.serverStatus().connections`
{ "current" : 204, "available" : 0, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(931) }

Comment: if you are here for this error and java socket is closed take a look at: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/prematurely-reached-end-of-stream/139733

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Rhangaun's answer here is my solution in code of JAVA:

```
    public static DB getMongoDB() {

        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
        //build the connection options  
        builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);//set the max wait time in (ms)
        MongoClientOptions opts = builder.build();
        
    
        char[] password2 = "mypassword".toCharArray();
        
        MongoCredential credential2 = MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "databasename",password2);
        
       
        //add your option to the connection 

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("server ip",27017), Arrays.asList(credential2),opts);
        //use your database 
        cachedDb = mongoClient.getDB("databasename");
        
    return cachedDb;

}
```

Here is my research link:http://3t.io/blog/how-to-prevent-your-connection-from-dropping-with-hosted-mongodb-instances/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I was using this constructor to build connection but always get exception: MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("203.11.83.230",27017), Arrays.asList(credential2))              I changed to differnet one with MongoClientOptions everything works fine for me

Answer (score 26):

I found it in some documentation:

**For long running applications, it is often prudent to enable "keepAlive" with a number of milliseconds. Without it, after some period of time you may start to see "connection closed" errors for what seems like no reason.**

Check if this helps. When you connect to mongoDB you can pass socket options to it. I am from node background we use following options to keep it alive.

```
server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 100,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It has been deprecated as it's now defaults to true. So it's always enabled: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#socketKeepAlive-boolean-

Answer (score 8):

I solve this problem by set sslEnabled to true,code sample：

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    List<ServerAddress> saList = new ArrayList<>();
    saList.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-00-75shm.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));
    saList.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-01-75shm.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));
    saList.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-02-75shm.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));

    char[] pwd =  "password".toCharArray();
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "admin", pwd);

    //set sslEnabled to true here
    MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.primaryPreferred())
            .retryWrites(true)
            .requiredReplicaSetName("Cluster0-shard-0")
            .maxConnectionIdleTime(6000)
            .sslEnabled(true)
            .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(saList, credential, options);     
    return mongoClient;
}
```

Addition: my client jar is org.mongodb.mongodb-driver 3.6.4,server is mongodb atlas M0 3.6.6 on GCP

Comment: if your SSL was enabled, then where were the certificates? and where is the code for the same in above piece of code.

Answer (score 6):

#### This worked for me in spring boot and cloud based mongo (Atlas clustered instances).

Edit application.properties like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://username:password@solarsystem-1tpu0.mongodb.net/dbname
```

For **regular mongo instances** (non-clustered) use this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://username:password@solarsystem-shard-00-00-1tpu0.mongodb.net:27017,hostname2:27017/dbname?ssl=true
```

- If you want to set other **connection options**, you can chain
  multiple parameters using '&' ; documentation here:
  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html
- If you were using other **spring.data.mongodb parameters**, you should
  **remove all of them** otherwise spring won't read
  spring.data.mongodb.uri

Answer (score 0):

To me it was a whole different issue - I was using [mongo-java-server](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/mongo-java-server) with [Fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) and ended up getting this error. Turns out that [old versions of it are not compatible with `FieldType.DECIMAL128` conversions](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/mongo-java-server/issues/45).

Updating it to the latest one (1.36.0 currently) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Mongodb end the connection. You need to increase the timeout of the Mongodb Driver here is an example code.

```
 MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    //build the connection options
    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(86400000);//set the max wait time in (ms)
    MongoClientOptions opts = builder.build();




    final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();


    morphia.mapPackage("com.java.code");


    final String hostURL = "host_url";
            

    MongoCredential  credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("username","database","Password".toCharArray()); 

    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress(hostURL);


    List<MongoCredential> credentialList = new ArrayList<>();
    credentialList.add(credential);


   final MongoClient client = new MongoClient(address,credentialList,opts);




    // create the Datastore connecting to the default port on the local host
    datastore  = morphia.createDatastore(client,"datastore");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after taking two steps.

**First one:**
Preparation of the appropriate MongoClientSettings object containing the key settings for our Mongo client.

```
private MongoClientSettings getMongoClientSettings() {
    return MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .retryWrites(true)
        .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(poolSettings -> poolSettings
                .minSize(5)
                .maxSize(300)
                .maxConnectionIdleTime(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .applyToSocketSettings(socketSettings -> socketSettings
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        .build();
}
```

*maxConnectionIdleTime – the maximum time a connection can be unused. A zero value indicates no limit to the idle time.*

*maxSize - The maximum number of connections allowed. Those connections will be kept in the pool when idle. Once the pool is exhausted, any operation requiring a connection will block waiting for an available connection. Default is 100*

*minSize - The minimum number of connections. Those connections will be kept in the pool when idle, and the pool will ensure that it contains at least this minimum number. Default is 0*

**Second one:**
Increasing the default timeout in application.properties / application.yaml file (or the one you already have)

```
mongodb:
 database: your_db_name
 authDatabase: admin
 config:
   enabled: true
   write:
     writeConcern:
       isMajority: true
     timeout:
       milliseconds: 100000
```

Check it out and it should work :)